# `Undefined symbol: ossl_sha3_512_functions` when trying to build the Kadena chainweb-node Haskell project

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, kadena

I've been trying to compile the Kadena chainweb-node project from source ([via the docs found here](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node#building-from-source)) in a docker container running the `arm64v8/ubuntu` base image on an Apple M1 host machine and I keep getting errors. Thanks to the super helpful folks in the #haskell IRC channel, I've made it over a number of small hurdles, but the build still fails with:

`Undefined symbol: ossl_sha3_512_functions`

I can not find any resources on how to fix this but one of the #haskell community members informed me that these symbols are not provided by the openssl 3.0 API. That person created an issue here: https://github.com/larskuhtz/hs-hashes/issues/14

I've found that I can use the docker base image `haskell:8` which comes preinstalled with ghc, cabal, and openssl 1.1.1 to `cabal build` chainweb-node successfully using a slightly different set of apt-get dependencies. However, when trying to `cabal install` the binaries so that I can run `chainweb-node`, I get:

```
Failed to build chainweb-2.14.1. The failure occurred during the configure
step.
Build log (
/root/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/chainweb-2.14.1-36aedf5adc1967eb17358e6434b6fd51bc7e64082f6c12e0df40ddafece6ff69.log
):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/cabal-install.-838/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-838/chainweb-2.14.1/dist/setup/setup.hs, /tmp/cabal-install.-838/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-838/chainweb-2.14.1/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/cabal-install.-838/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-838/chainweb-2.14.1/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring chainweb-2.14.1...
setup: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
criterion -any,
data-ordlist >=0.4.7,
resource-pool >=0.2,
retry >=0.7,
statistics >=0.15,
tasty-json >=0.1


cabal: Failed to build chainweb-2.14.1. See the build log above for details.
```

I've tried `cabal install criterion` and the other missing deps, one by one, but the `cabal install` gives me the same errors.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me get a working `chainweb-node` binary built from source and installed using docker?